# Saving a Python file with Emacs changed the indentations

Tags: python, emacs

I've never had this happen before, but when using Emacs23 on Ubuntu 14.04, I've twice had the indentations change when I've tried to save the file - e.g.

```
     if classRowDict[currClass] != rowCtr:
        sys.exit("About to enter %s in row %d, instead of row %d" % (currClass, rowCtr, classRowDict[currClass]))
     else:
        data=re.findall("\d+\.?\d*",currLine)
```

becomes

```
     if classRowDict[currClass] != rowCtr:
 sys.exit("About to enter %s in row %d, instead of row %d" % (currClass, rowCtr, classRowDict[currClass]))
     else:
 data=re.findall("\d+\.?\d*",currLine)
```

For larger code blocks, this is a bigger problem. I'm going to fix things using Emacs24, but this is the second time this has happened. Has anyone seen something like this, where just saving (ctrlX - S) causes Emacs to change the indentations of a Python (.py) file? If so, how should I avoid this, or at least fix it in the future?

Comment: What mode do you use to edit Python files ? https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Major-Modes.html

Comment: @JulienPalard I'm using Py Mode. The minor mode is Outline (Outl), although Font Lock also seems to be selected.

Comment: Py Mode ? Don't know it, can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some debugging tips:

- Try looking at the variable "before-save-hook" to see what might be running when you save.

  Try running Emacs as "emacs -q" to remove anything configured in your .emacs file

  Try removing blocks of code to see if something is screwing up with the indentation of the rest of the file.

Comment: Also, does it reproduce if you just mark the whole buffer and hit Ctrl-M-\ (or, equivalently, M-x indent-region)?  That way you can tell if it's the indentation semantics, or something else messing with the code.

Comment: I'll have to wait until it happens again (possibly soon, since I'm going to try Python editing in my Emacs23 again), but The change of indents, so far, only seems to happen with ctrl-X S, if I hit undo (ctrl-shift _), I recover the original identing.

Comment: Somehow when I was cutting/pasting new things to my .emacs fiel ,(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'whitespace-cleanup) got added.... sigh... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As said, most likely some hook does it. If you don't see the cause, please try from emacs -Q, load python-mode.el and file a bug-report at

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode